# Which "Application Part" and "Application Data Sheet" do I use for the provisional patent document?

Tags: patent-applications

While trying to submit my (personally-made) patent documents on EFS-Web I ran into an issue. I'm assuming that I should upload the pdf document of the provisional patent application in the "Attach Documents" section of EFS-Web, but then it asks for two areas to narrow down the type of file I'm submitting:

[image]

"Application Part" and "Application Data Sheet" are listed above the two drop-down boxes. I think the correct selection would be "General Transmittal" for the "Application Part" and "Transmittal of New Application" for "Application Data Sheet" but I'm not entirely sure.

The two drop-down boxes are shown here:

[image]

[image]

and here is the "Application Data Sheet" drop-down box after "General Transmittal" is selected for "Application Part":

[image]

Could someone let me know what these choices really mean and then which of these applies to the file I'm submitting? I'm not a lawyer so I'm sorry if this all comes across as I have no idea what I'm doing (mostly because I don't).

Again I want to find a place to actually upload the file that contains my entire provisional patent application, with figures and descriptions and whatnot. Not a form or something else, just the main file.

Comment: I think [this](https://www.uspto.gov/sites/default/files/ebc/portal/efs/dct_new_app_tutorial.pdf)  will be of help. The application goes to Application Part, but I am not sure if you are to split up the documents into a Spec document, Claims document, Abstract document (as it would appear from the linked PDF file)... or if there is an option to select the different pages for each section of the application within the same application document (this is why I am not putting this up as an answer).

Comment: huh, so we might just be better off splitting up the document into those sections it seems like? Is that what is typically done by patent applicants through EFS-Web?

Comment: There is an option to indicate that the file has multiple parts - then you are asked for page ranges for each part.

Comment: Ok this makes sense, thanks for the help!

Comment: If one has abstract, drawing, specification, claims as separate files than may browse and upload respective files by choosing  'Application Part' and than type of file from selection on the right side drop down. Else one may upload as 'Transmittal of New Application' available as the last option on right side drop down. Also, provisional cover sheet and entity status (for claiming fee concession) are to be submitted. For web application ADS and Fee required are generated automatically.